# How to keep ImageMagick up-to-date on Heroku-18 stack?

Tags: security, heroku, imagemagick, rmagick

At time of writing, the ImageMagick version installed on the Heroku-18 stack is a few years out-of-date (version 6.9.7-4 released 14/Jan/2017).

How would you recommend keeping ImageMagick up-to-date on the Heroku-18 stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku support suggested a couple of options: either install ImageMagick via the apt-get buildpack (https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt), or use one of the ImageMagick buildpacks (https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=imagemagick).

*Buildpacks have access to your environment and if compromised would pose a significant risk. So I'll add that **if you do use a third-party, non-Heroku buildpack, you should consider forking that buildpack's repo and use your trusted fork instead** of relying on a third-party's repo that could be modified maliciously without your knowledge.*